# gwt firefox getAbsoluteLeft()

Tags: gwt, css-position

I'm seeing a truly weird behavior while trying to set a popup relative to another element in GWT. It seems like setting the popup position (an independent, floating element) changes the answer I get from calls like getAbsoluteRight() or getAbsoluteLeft() for a completely different element, which is static on the page and does not move visually.

I added some print statements to check what was going on, so here is the code:

```
System.out.println(item.td);
int position = item.td.getAbsoluteRight()-offsetWidth;
System.out.println("left/right:" + item.td.getAbsoluteLeft() + "/" + item.td.getAbsoluteRight() + ". sent:" + (item.td.getAbsoluteRight() - offsetWidth) + "=" + position);
popup.setPopupPosition(position, item.td.getAbsoluteBottom());
System.out.println("left/right:" + item.td.getAbsoluteLeft() + "/" + item.td.getAbsoluteRight() + ". sent:" + (item.td.getAbsoluteRight() - offsetWidth) + "=" + position);
popup.addStyleName("bigger");
System.out.println("left/right:" + item.td.getAbsoluteLeft() + "/" + item.td.getAbsoluteRight() + ". sent:" + (item.td.getAbsoluteRight() - offsetWidth) + "=" + position);
System.out.println(item.td);
```

Here is the result on Chrome

```
Menu displayed, widths: 81/340=340
<td class="hover">Daniel?</td>    
left/right:1104/1185. sent:845=845
left/right:1121/1202. sent:862=845
left/right:1121/1202. sent:862=845
<td class="hover">Daniel?</td>
```

Here is the result on Firefox

```
Menu displayed, widths: 81/340=340
<td class="hover">Daniel?</td>
left/right:1254/1335. sent:995=995
left/right:1273/1354. sent:1014=995
left/right:1273/1354. sent:1014=995
<td class="hover">Daniel?</td>
```

so the left/right coordinates of the fixed element suddenly change (X coordinate goes from 1254 to 1273) after calling setPopupPosition(), while the relevant element actually stays in the same place (visually). I really have no idea how it happens as the popup doesn't even know of the existence of that element. Even more, while I can reproduce the error consistently, it does not happen if I switch the popup content...

... incidentally, I compared the coordinates given by firefox with a screenshot of the page, and the return values are not only wrong, but impossible given my screen size (1366x768) and no scrolling.

I could probably try setting the position twice, as the second value is actually the correct one, but I would really like to understand what is going on here...

Many thanks!

Comment: There may be no scrolling, but is there an appearance of scrollbars once you set the position on the popup?  Is the change idempotent, in the sense that setting position once will change the other item's position, but resetting the position again will not change the other item's position any further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differ is exactly 150 pixels. (May be total of 75 pix in left side)
Have you checked page against: http://validator.w3.org/
There's often differences within the margin/padding (also borders in IE).

As i get out of your `getAbsoluteRight()-offsetWidth` code, you using the `td` to get absolute right. But setting the position on the `popup`. This should mean that you have some borders/margins/padding between the `popup` and the `td` content.

The `getAbsoluteLeft()` and `getAbsoluteRight()` *(as well as Top and Bottom)* are all calculated based on their parental element's scroll and offset positions.

Also an empty object can often end up in a default width. But as soon as you enter a content, the size adapts to its content.

Comment: So to be honest I no longer work at the place (it's been a year and a half) and have no access to the code. But I'll accept your answer in order to have some closure. GWT code is supposed to be cross-browser though, so any such difference should be accounted for,